# Start Service with Sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, services, nodejs

I am trying to run an Express API server with sudo permissions and have it automatically start on boot.

The API needs access to bcm2835 library, and I get the following when trying to run node server.js

> bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied 
>   /home/pi/Documents/node_modules/rpio/lib/rpio.js:104
>   return bindfunc(optarg);
>
> Error: Could not initialize bcm2835 library
>   at bindcall (/home/pi/...) etc.

However it boots up fine running sudo node server.js.

I have created a service file at /etc/systemd/system as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node API
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/pi/Documents/server.js
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=controller
User=root
Group=root
Environment=

TimeoutStopSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I found some guidance here and here, but they seem slightly off, since a sub-command needs sudo/root privileges.

When running `service controller start` from the command line it prompts for a username and password.

**How can I run this service with proper permissions so it boots up with the Pi?**

Comment: Your script is the issue!

Comment: I see... How do I give the proper permissions to the script?

Comment: No, the "asking for password" is the issue and I assume controller is your script!

Comment: `server.js` is my script that calls `/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/rpio/lib/rpio.js`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no"...

Answer (score 4):

you need to allow the following commands in the sudoers file:

```
systemctl start <your-systemd-service>

systemctl stop <your-systemd-service>

systemctl restart <your-systemd-service>

systemctl enable <your-systemd-service>
```

dont use the service command.

Remember to replace the service name with your systemd service.
For example if your service file is with name:

```
/etc/systemd/system/controller.service
```

then it should be:

```
systemctl start controller.service

systemctl stop controller.service

systemctl restart controller.service

systemctl enable controller.service
```

also , you will need to do:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

after you place you service file in systemd

**Adding commonads in sudoers:**

https://www.atrixnet.com/allow-an-unprivileged-user-to-run-a-certain-command-with-sudo/

example command:

```
<your-user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start controller.service
```

Comment: Where is the sudoers file?

Comment: just type visudo as root , it will open the config file and u need to allow your user thoese commands

Comment: remember to replace the service name with the name of your systemd service

Comment: I get an error after I save the file, `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 15` and so on for each line I try to add.

Comment: How do I edit as root when I'm logged in as another user?

Comment: you need to check the syntax of how to add entries in sudoers file

Comment: you need to be root to edit the sudoers file , or ask your system admin

Comment: allowing commands in sudeors file doesnt mean that you just copy paste them , they have specifc syntax , i have just pointed out the commands u need to allow , how to allow them is a different question

Comment: I can run `sudo visudo`... Is that good enough?

Comment: https://www.atrixnet.com/allow-an-unprivileged-user-to-run-a-certain-command-with-sudo/

Comment: Even when running as root with `su root` then `visudo` I get a syntax error.

Comment: Hm. Maybe it's slightly different on Raspbian?