# ubuntu 20.04 service autostart

Tags: sudo, systemd, autostart

I have a process which I start using `sudo ./whatever`

I want to make it a service which starts automatically.

Have created a .service file and put it in the `/etc/systemd/system` but it won't start the process. I suspect the problem is sudo related but don't know how to get round it. This is the script I followed

```
[Unit]
Description=what
After=network.target
[Service]
User=w
Group=w
WorkingDirectory=/home/w/test
ExecStart=/home/w/test/whatever
KillMode=process
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=what
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: If you were to login as 'w', would 'w' need to use sudo to run the application?

Comment: Did you try to start the process manually ? sudo service "your_service" start. Or try : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089260/start-service-with-sudo

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `User=w`, `Group=w` if you need to run the script as root.

```
[Unit]
Description=what
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/w/test
ExecStart=/home/w/test/whatever
KillMode=process
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=what
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable and start it:

```
sudo systemctl enable yourservice
sudo systemctl start yourservice
```

Modify your script and add:

```
echo "Starting my CustoM script" | logger
```

And after reboot check if it has been executed:

```
journalctl -b | grep CustoM
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the pointers. It turns out it was a permissions issue and had to change ownership of the folder and also the service file.
Everyday's a school day !

Comment: Hi Koj1888,  I have the same problem - what directory did you have to change ownership of (I am guessing /etc/systemd/system) and to what did you change it?  I am thinking 'root', but 'root' already owns the directory and file?